# cURL not returning expected webpage content

Tags: curl

I am trying to do a search "site:aa.com credit cards fax" through the following, both google and bing failed, very puzzle as why this is happening.

Google:

```
curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" -o foo1 -L "https://www.google.com/#q=site:aa.com+%22credit+card%22+fax&start=0"
```

Bing:

```
curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" -o foo1 -L "http://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3aaa.com+%22credit+card%22+fax&qs=n&pq=site%3aaa.com+%22credit+card%22+fax&sc=8-29&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=264B54ADDA5C45E69C85E98DF9AE279E&first=1&FORM=PERE"
```

This is done through a shared server GNU/Linux, but I doubt this has anything to do with server configuration.

Comment: Maybe you want `#q=site...` to be `?q=site...` for the Google one?

Comment: same thing, not working

Comment: Please clarify: what is the expected output and what is the actual output?